# Control more than one PWM with separate timings

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, microprocessors

So I am programming my first AVR C project (ATMEGA32U4) controlling three individual LED's red, green and blue.
I am able to control one PWM pin / timer although I can't seem to control more than one. I feel that I am missing something with the registers. Here is what I did to achieve it with one pin / timer:

```
void pwm8bit(){
    // PWM Pins: PB6 PB7 PC6
    DDRB |= (1 << PORTB6) | (1 << PORTB7);
    DDRC |= (1 << PORTC6);

    TCCR0A = (1 << COM0A1) | (1 << WGM00) | (1 << WGM01);

    TIMSK0 = (1 << TOIE0);

    OCR3A = (RotaryRedValue / 100.0) * 255.0; // PC6
    OCR0A = (RotaryGreenValue / 100.0) * 255.0; // PB7
    OCR1B = (RotaryBlueValue / 100.0) * 255.0; // PB6

    TCCR0B = (1 << CS00);
}
```

The green one works and the others stay on permanently, I assumed this was because of the timer being `TCCR"0A"`, so I did try adding `TCCR"3A"` with the same values for the red (no luck here).
I then took a look in the documentation for the same timer register and noticed that it had a different COM, WGM and CS registers associated with them and tried to match them accordingly. Again with no luck.

Can some one help me get on the right path?

Thank you, 
Jamie

Comment: You're right you also need to set up the TCCR1 and TCCR3 registers. Note that the WGM bits have different configurations for timer 1 and 3 than for timer 0. Which bits did set when you tried?

Comment: Timer 1 and 3 can actually control 3 PWM signals each by setting the OCRnA, OCRnB and OCRnC registers. Makes things a bit cleaner, and you have more timers left to use for other purposes.

Comment: @osvein Hi, I tried this `TCCR3A = (1 << COM3A1) | (1 << WGM31) | (1 << WGM30);` I didn't get anywhere though.

Comment: That's not the right combination of WGM bits for Timer 3. You need 8-bit fast PWM. Refer to table 14-4 in the datasheet. I strongly recommend you read the whole chapter. You'll also have to set the right prescaler bits in the TCCR3B register.

Comment: How would I use the same timer for the two pins as mentioned previously?

Comment: Also did you mean table 14-3? That one says Fast PWM

Comment: @osvein I can't come to any conclision that it is any other WGM bits. Here is what I see in the documentation [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/gflW9PX)